# Running containerized PyTest

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I am learning how to run containerized PyTests and I am failing to run a test with arguments.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:2
ADD main.py /
RUN pip install docker
RUN pip install fake_useragent
RUN pip install pytest
RUN pip install requests
CMD ["pytest", "main.py --html=report.html"]
```

But I tried all kinds of CMD/RUN variations I found online.
Anybody has a clue?
The full project is here if helps:

https://github.com/pavelzag/DockerSDKLearn

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: ERROR: file not found: main.py --html=report.html

Answer (score 2):

`"main.py --html=report.html"` will be passed in pytest as a single argument and will appear in `sys.argv[1]` there. Hence pytest is trying to locate a file with the exact same name with stuff like `--html` in it. You should fully tokenize the command:

```
CMD ["pytest", "main.py", "--html=report.html"]
```